# Can I use the browsers built in HTML5 email validation in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was working on a very basic HTML form and was asked to add email validation. The form is sent via an AJAX post, so I can't use the standard HTML validation with a submit button:

```
<form>
    <input type="email" id="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I could just add some regex to the JS, but this made me wonder, is it possible interact with the browsers built-in validation from JS?

E.g. A built-in function or property that could be give the inputs current state in terms of validation (valid/invalid)

Something like:

```
var valid = document.getElementById("email").isValid();
```

Comment: Why can't you use the built-in validation? The validation happens before the onsubmit event is triggered.

Comment: @JJJ I'm not submitting a form, just using inputs values in an AJAX post inside JS. This is more an "I wonder if this is possible" rather than an "I need a solution".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can using the `checkValidity` method on each element:

```
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var isValid = email.checkValidity();

if (isValid) {
    // Submit form
}
```

You can also use the `validity` property on an element to check which validation constraints failed:

```
var validity = email.validity;
if (validity.valueMissing) {
    return 'Please enter your email';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, using *Constraint validation API methods*.

You can find out the details in here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation#Validating_forms_using_JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

You are thinking on something like this:

JS

```js
<script>
function checkEmail() {
    var x = document.getElementById("email");
      if(x.value.includes("@")){
      // do something or just continue
      }else{alert("Not valid email!")
      }

}
</script>
```

Comment: just for clarification, this answer is not valid because a string like "@@@" will be considered as valid, which is not. Another failure scenarios are "hola@", "@chao", "!@!", etc

Comment: and it is not correct because it doesn't use the browsers built in HTML5 email validation as asked in the question.